# Windows Defender shows GUI at PC start up

Tags: windows-defender

I am running Windows 7 64 bit on my PC. For a few weeks now, when I boot up my PC, the Windows Defender interface displays and I have to close it with the x each time. Even if I disable Defender, I still get a message saying that it is turned off and asking me if I would like to enable it. It's no big deal, but it's a bit annoying and I'd like to find a fix for it if possible.

Comment: Does the popup say anything special?

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> key or click on Start button and type `msconfig` in the search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Select the *Startup* tab (the fourth one).
3. Uncheck Windows Defender (manufacturer Microsoft) or anything that you think is malicious software (uncheck all unknown manufacturers).
4. Restart your machine.